# CodeIgniter custom encrypt function

Tags: codeigniter, encryption

In my previous project i was created a custom encryption function to login. How can i use it in CI. here is my code

```
function sha_password($username,$password){
$username = strtoupper($username);
$password = strtoupper($password);
return SHA1($username.':'.$password);
}
```

and i was called like that to get encrypted password

```
$password = strtoupper(sha_password($username,$password));
```

how can i do it to work in CI? :?

Answer (score 2):

you can place it in various places:

1. a model - if you have a model for a user, $user->getEncryptedPassword();
2. a library - in my project i have libuser that has the encryption function, so i call it by $this->libuser->encrypt_password();
3. a controller (MY_Controller for example) - create a function and call it by $this->encrypt_user_password(..)
4. just drop it in some of the files that will always be loaded, in config or something
5. if you don't plan on changing it, just do $encpass = sha1(strtoupper($username.':'.$password)); although i wouldn't go there.

options 1 and 2 are most recommended

Comment: Yes i have. This my user model '<?php
class Membership_model extends CI_Model{
 function sha_password($username,$password){
  $username = strtoupper($username);
  $password = strtoupper($password);
  return SHA1($username.':'.$password);
 }
 
 function validate(){
  $this->db->where('username',$this->input->post('username'));
  $this->db->where('sha_pass_hash',$this->input->post('password'));
  $query = $this->db->get('account');
  if($query->num_rows == 1){
   return TRUE;
  }
 }
}' i don't know how to use sha_password function ooz of i'm newbie in CI. Btw thanks for your answer

Comment: in your case, in order to call the sha_password() method, you need an instance of Membership_model ($m->sha_password()), or you could make this method static (Membership_model::sha_password()). either that, or create a library with this function

Comment: when i use like that i got a fatal error call to undifined function 'function validate(){
  $this->db->where('username',$this->input->post('username'));
  $this->db->where('sha_pass_hash',sha_password($this->input->post('password')));
  $query = $this->db->get('account');
  if($query->num_rows == 1){
   return TRUE;
  }
 }' how can i use it?

Comment: here is my controller to validate 'function validate_credentials(){
  $this->load->model('membership_model');
  $query = $this->membership_model->validate();
  //if the user's credentials validated....
  if($query){
   $data = array(
    'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
    'is_logged_in' => true
   );
   $this->session->set_userdata($data);
   redirect('site/members_area');
  }else{
   //if not validate login page again
   $this->index();
  }
 }'

Comment: i did not understand where you placed it. did you put it in the model? if so, within the model you can call it by $this->sha_password() and outside the model, you need the instance, ie $m->sha_password(). i think where you're going is $this->membership_model->sha_password()